# Как поменять текущую дату?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, дата, datetime

Использую Ubuntu Linux 15.10. Нужно поменять текущую локальную дату. В `man date` написано, что для этого используется команда `sudo date --set=STRING`. Но дата не менятся -- команда `date` выводит неизменённую дату на экран.

Comment: так надо указать дату (точнее, дату и время): `$ sudo date -s '2016/10/12 16:09'`

Comment: Надо поменять дату или синхронизировать время, чтобы часы в ОС показывали точное время?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Параметры системы > Время и дата.
2. Сменить флажок "автоматически через интернет" на "вручную".
3. Сменить дату.

Если через терминал: Наберите команду date, чтобы посмотреть текущие дату и время.

Если необходимо изменить их, воспользуйтесь следующим форматом команды:

```
date MMDDhhmmCCYY.ss
  MM — месяц,
  DD — день месяца,
  hh — часы,
  mm — минуты,
  CCYY — 4 цифры года,
  ss — секунды
```

Обратите внимание: дату и время может изменять только root-пользователь, поэтому синтаксис изменится вот так: `sudo date MMDDhhmmCCYY.ss`

Answer (score 0):

Редактируется следующими командами:

```
date -s "12 OCT 2016 18:00:00"
```

или

```
date --set="12 OCT 2016 18:00:00"
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky думаю, на `man date` основано. Как бы вы дополнили этот ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Как мне кажется, было бы полезно пояснить, почему команды именно такие (возможно есть вариации?), дать какую–либо более высокоуровневую рекомендацию по настройке и использованию дат в Ubuntu.

Comment: Команда 'date' меняет только системное время, т.е. ячейку в памяти  ядра. После перезагрузки это значение может быть утрачено. Для того, что бы переписать системное время в память BIOS, используется команда **hwclock -w**.

Comment: Есть ещё одни грабли. Если на этом же компе установлена Windows, то может возникнуть конфликт. Дело в том. что Windows хранит в BIOS местное время, а Linux - GMT. Поэтому, при последовательных перезагрузках Linux/Windows будут наблюдаться весьма забавные вещи...

Comment: У меня раньше на одном компьютере стояла и ubuntu и windows, но почему-то настройки времени сбивались только на Windows.